# How to reference correctly the original object when changing scope

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I totally begin using RequireJS because I felt its usefulness but I'm still stuck in a simple programming problem: when I run out of scope (like when I am coding inside a jQuery callback'd function), I don't know the exact proper way to refer to where I was.
I have an example: this code is in the src/dir of my project, I have jquery.js and require.js in lib/ .

```
// src/main.js

define(function() {
    return {
        setup: function(settings){
            this.settings = settings;
        },

        start: function(){
            this.initScr();
        },

        initScr: function(){
            var screen = $('<canvas>').attr({
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            });
            $('body').append(screen);
            this.DOM.screen = screen[0];
            $(window).resize(function(){
                require(['game/main'], function(game) {
                    console.log(this);
                    game.DOM.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
                    game.DOM.screen.height = window.innerHeight;
                });
            });
        },

        settings: {},
        DOM: {}
    };
});
```

The problem here is, when in my "module", specifically in a jQuery callback here,
how can I change a property of the module's object from this callback?
I can't use the "this" keyword here because it's no more the one that I want.
What is the best solution?
What I did here with the require make me feel really strange.

Thanks for reading

**Edit:**

Finally, I did that, helped by pax162 's answer.

```
define(function() {
    var initScr =  function(){
                var screen = $('<canvas>').attr({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight
                });
                $('body').append(screen);
                DOM.screen = screen[0];
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    DOM.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
                    DOM.screen.height = window.innerHeight;
                });
            };

    var start = function(){
                initScr();
            };

    var setup = function(settings1){
                settings = settings1;
            };

    var settings = {};

    var DOM = {};

    return {
            setup: setup,
            start: start,
            initScr:initScr,
            settings: settings,
            DOM: DOM
    };
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve, but loading a module inside a resize handler doesn't feel like the optimum way to go about it. What the user perceives as a single resize could trigger lots of resize events.

Comment: @Oriol I want to set my DOM.screen in my $(window).resize() , but I need a reference to the object, I think it's not optimal to use a require() here because I'm already in a module loaded by require().

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm am even not sure if the module will be loaded again... will it be ? I thought RequireJS load the first time but since it's the second require() of 'game/main' ?
Edit: Actually, yes, the module is not loaded again in memory, it is the same, because I see the same DOM.screen in the require(), so I'm not "loading" the module again, i just want a reference to it, but I don't know if it is a good way to do

Comment: But what if the user doesn't resize the window at all? Then the module will never be loaded. It just seems an odd place to do it.

Comment: @nnnnnn : The module require'd was the module I was already inside, so the module was already loaded in fact, but that wasn't a good place to put a require at all I totally agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, and keep the scope:

```
define(function() {




var initScr =  function(){
            var screen = $('<canvas>').attr({
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            });
            $('body').append(screen);
            DOM.screen = screen[0];
            $(window).resize(function(){
                require(['game/main'], function(game) {
                    //console.log(this);
                    game.DOM.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
                    game.DOM.screen.height = window.innerHeight;
                });
            });
        };

var start = function(){
            initScr();
        };

var setup = function(settings1){
            settings = settings1;
        };

var settings = {};

var DOM = {};

    return {
        setup: setup,
        start: start,
        initScr:initScr,
        settings: settings,
        DOM: DOM
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you @pax162 , but now the problem is that "this" is referring to the window object inside the initScr method, not the module's object.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript 1.8.5 or higher, [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the solution I prefer. The documentation says that bind:

> Creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

In your case, your **original** code could be modified so that the resize handler is set like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    this.DOM.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.DOM.screen.height = window.innerHeight;
}.bind(this));
```

At the time `bind` is called `this` has the value you want. Upon resize, the return value of `bind` will be called, which is a function for which `this` is bound to the value you wanted it to have.